# The image of a periodic nonconstant maximal integral curve is an immersed submanifold diffeomorphic to $S^1$

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, submanifold

This is problem 9-1 from John Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds. Suppose $M$ is a smooth manifold $X$ is a smooth vector field on $M$ and $\gamma$ is a maximal integral curve of $X$.

Show that the image of $\gamma$ is an immersed submanifold of $M$, diffeomorphic to $S^1$ if $\gamma$ is periodic and nonconstant.

If $\gamma$ is periodic and nonconstant, we have the period $T$, and we can consider the smooth covering map $\pi:\mathbb{R} \to S^1$ defined by $\pi(x)=e^{2\pi it/T}$. Since $\gamma$ is constant on the fibers of $\pi$ it descends to a smooth map $\tilde{\gamma}:S^1 \to M$ with $\tilde{\gamma}\circ \pi=\gamma$. Since $\gamma(t)=\gamma(t')$ iff $t-t'=kT$ for some $k\in \mathbb{Z}$, $\tilde{\gamma}$ is injective. Hence, $\tilde{\gamma}$ is an injective smooth immersion and its image is an immersed submanifold of $M$ diffeomorphic to $S^1$ using Proposition 5.18 of the book (Images of Immersions as Submanifolds) which is Suppose $M$ is a smooth manifold with or without boundary, $N$ is a smooth manifold, and $F:N \to M$ is an injective smooth immersion. Let $S=F(N).$ Then $S$ has a unique topology and smooth structure such that it is a smooth submanifold of $M$ and such that $F:N\to S$ is a diffeomorphism onto its image.

My question is how can we say that the image of the original curve $\gamma$ is also an immersed submanifold of $M$ diffeomorphic to $S^1$? $\gamma$ is not injective, even though it is an immersion so I cannot apply the Proposition. I know that its image is the same as the image of $\tilde{\gamma}$, but $\gamma$ has a different domain so I don't think I can just translate results about $\tilde{\gamma}$ to $\gamma$. How can I resolve this issue? I would greatly appreciate some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote from Lee:

> An immersed submanifold $S$ of $M$ is a subset $S \subset M$ endowed with a
> topology (not necessarily the subspace topology) with respect to which it is a topological manifold (without boundary), and a smooth structure with respect to which the inclusion map $S \hookrightarrow M$ is a smooth immersion.

In other words,  an immersed submanifold $S$ of $M$ is the image of an injective immersion $i : S' \to M$.

Here is Problem 9-1 :

1. Suppose $M$ is a smooth manifold, $X \in \mathfrak X(M)$, and $\gamma$ is a maximal integral curve of $X$.
   (a) We say $\gamma$ is periodic if there is a number $T > 0$ such that $\gamma(t + T) = \gamma(t)$  for all $t \in \mathbb R$. Show that exactly one of the following holds:
   $\quad$ (1) $\gamma$ is constant.
   $\quad$ (2) $\gamma$ is injective.
   $\quad$ (3) $\gamma$ is periodic and nonconstant.
   (b) Show that if $\gamma$ is periodic and nonconstant, then there exists a unique positive number $T$ (called the *period of $\gamma$*) such that $\gamma(t) =  \gamma(t')$ if and only if $t -t' = kT$ for some $k \in \mathbb  Z$.
   (c) Show that the image of $\gamma$ is an immersed submanifold of $M$;  diffeomorphic to $\mathbb R, S^1$, or $\mathbb R^0$.

It seems that you accepted (b) and proved that if  $\gamma$ is periodic and nonconstant, then the image of $\gamma$ is an immersed submanifold of $M$ which is diffeomorphic to $S^1$. Actually the image of $\gamma$ is an embedded submanifold $M$ which is diffeomorphic to $S^1$.

I do not know whether you proved (a), but it is clear that your proof works for case (3).

To prove (a) let us distinguish a number of cases.

1. $\gamma$ is constant. This is (1) above.
2. $\gamma$ is non-constant.

Case 2 splits into two subcases:
$\quad$ (i) $\gamma$ is injective. This is (2) above. In this case the image of $\gamma$ is trivially an immersed submanifold.

$\quad$ (ii) $\gamma$ is not injective.

This means that $\gamma : J \to M$ has the property $\gamma(t_1) = \gamma(t_2) =: p$ for some points $t_1 < t_2$. By the translation lemma we may assume that $t_1 = 0$. Then $\gamma$ is the unique maximal integral curve with $\gamma(0) = p$. Now let $J^* = \{ t - t_2 \mid t \in J\}$ and $\gamma^* : J^* \to M, \gamma^*(t) = \gamma(t + t_2)$. By the translation lemma this is again an integral curve. Since $\gamma^1*(0) = \gamma(t_2) = p$, by maximality of $\gamma$ we must have $J^* \subset J$ and $\gamma^* = \gamma \mid_{J^*}$. This is possible only when $J = \mathbb R$ and $\gamma^* = \gamma$. This means that $\gamma$ is periodic with period $t_2$.

Thus we get (3) above.

Comment: Why is the image of $\gamma$ an embedded submanifold of $M$? If I understand things correctly, the image of $\gamma$, that is, $\gamma(\mathbb{R})$ is an immersed submanifold diffeomorphic to $S^1$ because it is equal to the image of $\tilde{\gamma(S^1)}$, where as I've shown $\tilde{\gamma}$ is an injective immersion. Then $S^1$ is compact, so by the closed map lemma $\tilde{\gamma}$ is an embedding, so the image is an embedded submanifold?

Comment: The reason I asked this question is I'm not sure if I can say that the image of $\gamma$ is an immersed submanifold because $\gamma$ itself is not an injective immersion. But the descended map $\tilde{\gamma}$ is and their images are equal as set. So I guess I have to interpret this as meaning the image of $\gamma$ is the image of an injective immersion (an embedding actually) of another map $\tilde{\gamma}$.

Comment: @nomadicmathematician This is correct. In the periodic case $\gamma$ is not injective, but we are only interested in the image $S= \gamma(\mathbb R)$. To decide whether $S$ is an immersed submanifold its **origin** as the image of some immersion is completely irrelevant. You constructed the injective immersion $\tilde \gamma : S^1 \to M$ such that $S = \tilde \gamma(S^1)$. Thus, as you say, the image of $\gamma$, i.e. the set $S \subset M$ is the image of the injective immersion $\tilde \gamma$. By definition $S$ is therefore an immersed submanifold.